# Task :app:buildDebugStaticWebviewAssets FAILED

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
> Task :app:buildDebugStaticWebviewAssets FAILED
```

./tools/build-webview: error: unexpected destination directory '/d/CODE_WORKSPACE/zulip-mob/zulip-mobile/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/out/webview' (expected target in Android build dir)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:buildDebugStaticWebviewAssets'.

  > Process 'command 'bash'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
55 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 54 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: I was just trying to build and run zulip-mobile. I was following the instruction given at https://github.com/zulip/zulip-mobile/blob/master/docs/howto/build-run.md

Comment: I used `npx react-native run-android` command in git bash